# Get the value of the text field when a button is clicked using ajax and print using php

Tags: php, html, ajax

Please can anayone help me? How can I get the value of the text field when a button is clicked using ajax and print it using php? I got stuck reading topics about ajax and just don't understand it at all. i want the page not to reload when i clicked the button so that the value on the text field will not disappear....or is there other ways to do it than using ajax???

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <input type = 'text' name = 'fname'>
      <button type = 'button' >Submit</button>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: you don't know jquery? look at the example at bottom [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: actually you don't necessarily need AJAX for that, a simple PHP form evaluation will do it.
and i dont think anybody will do all the work for you, you need to do some reading and trying on your own. maybe that is a place to start: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: ummm.....the thing that i want to do exactly is for the page not to reload when i clicked the button so that the value of the text field will not disappear

Answer (score 0):

This will use strictly php to get and post the input
index.php

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

welcome.php:

```
Welcome  <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>
```

This will return the input value without any javascript.